# Draw a lot of single characters to a WinForms Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, paint

I have a custom WinForms control which could be described as some kind of terminal control (like a control containing Putty). According to this, the control should display a lot of characters, each with a different color and background color (worst case).

Currently I'm using the (kind of obsolete) `Graphics.MeasureString` method to determine the size of a single character in my fixed-size font so I can calculate the position of a character at a specific row and column. Then I use `Graphics.DrawString` to draw the characters. To optimize the performance I create a `BufferedGraphics` and group characters by their properties to draw consecutive characters with the same color with just one `DrawString` call. (Because one `DrawString` call per character is *really* slow.)

Now the problem is that `DrawString` apparently calculates the width of a character slightly different from `MeasureString`. When I draw a complete line at once, the resulting text width is different from what I calculated using the width of a single character multiplied by the character count of the line. It's just one or two pixels (or maybe less), but you can see it clearly - especially because I'm using anti-alias so you can even see a difference of just half a pixel.

The following sample code draws a long string `a` on the form's graphics, followed by character `'B'`. Then it draws just a `'B'` on the position calculated by measuring `a`.

```c#
var f = new Form {
    Width = 1200,
    Height = 500,
    Font = new Font("Consolas", 11, FontStyle.Regular)
};

f.Paint += delegate(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    var a = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    var size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(a, f.Font, new PointF(0, 0), StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

    using (var black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(a + "B", f.Font, black, 0, 0, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("B", f.Font, black, size.Width, 20, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    }
};

f.Show();
```

And if you look closely, you will see that the second `B` is about one pixel more right - at least with my display settings (100% dpi scale, ClearType enabled). Although one pixel is not much, when you draw lines using unicode characters `U+2500` through `U+257F` it looks pretty ugly if the characters aren't perfectly aligned.

Also I can't use the `TextRenderer` class because its `MeasureString` method returns integer values, but `DrawString` of course does not draw each character on a full pixel position (what would be required to align it with a position calculated using row/column and the measured integer character size).

So my question is: Is there any (efficient) method to draw strings which are perfectly aligned to their corresponding position calculated using the character size?

---

*P.S.:* `MeasureString` with a 200-character-string returns exactly 200 times the return value of `MeasureString` with a single-character-string.

Comment: Just a quick guess: Try to explicitly use Single / SizeF / PointF /RectangleF everywhere, I remember this solved a problem I had somewhere (to my great astonishment)..

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm already using `float`s everywhere. I tried it with `int`s when I was using the `TextRenderer` class. The difference was even larger then.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some similar issues with measuring the strings in Graphics. I have used SizeInPoints, a property from the class Font and multiplied it for the number of characters I have in the string... I dont't know if it helps.
If not it can be a "rounding" problem with the pixels... then I would try to scale up the font size (maybe 10 times), measure it and then divide it by 10 again when using the size to color the background.
I hope it helps. 
Good luck! Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having same issue.

It seems that the behavior depends on the font size.

After changing font with following code, this issue didn't occur.

```
Font = new Font("Consolas", 20.0F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
```

However, with another font size as below this issue still occurs.

```
Font = new Font("Consolas", 20.3F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
```

My guess on background of this issue: MeasureString and DrawString uses different layout routine and they have different characteristic in rounding error of float number. Only with 'simple' font size they gives same results.

Also, this issue didn't occur with bitmap fonts.